# How to perform efficient joins on two columns in pyspark

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a csv with user emails and their corresponding random unique ids.

```
email                 unique_id 
someone@example.com   kud0893
another@example.com   hgt4563
```

I also have a csv with messages they have sent each other.

```
Src_Username        message  Tgt_Username
someone@example.com message1 person@example.com
another@example.com message2 person2@example.com
```

Both csvs are millions of records long. I want to map the unique ids to their respective usernames efficiently in pyspark. I am currently doing the operation twice, once on each column. Is there a way to do the joins concurrently?

Here is my current code

```py
mapDF = sqlContext.read.format('csv').options(header='true',inferSchema='true').load('file:////map.csv')

tableDF = sqlContext.read.format('csv').options(header='true', inferSchema='true').load('file:////interactions.csv')

resultDF = tableDF.join(broadcast(mapDF), tableDF.Src_Username == mapDF.userid).withColumnRenamed("uniq_id","Src_Username").drop(tableDF.Src_Username).drop(mapDF.userid).persist()
resultDF = resultDF.join(broadcast(mapDF), tableDF.Tgt_Username == mapDF.userid).withColumnRenamed("uniq_id","Tgt_Username").drop(tableDF.Tgt_Username).drop(mapDF.userid).persist()
```

Comment: In the first dataset, is the email `someone@example.com` for both the unique_ids? Or was that a typing error?

Comment: typing error. Thank you for noticing. Edited

Comment: Not sure to understand what you mean by "doing the joins concurrently". Each join is already supposed to be concurrent (all workers are supposed to be full, if not, check the Spark UI). (Also you broadcast twice, be careful)

Comment: @falsafa A `df` should be Broadcast only when it is very small, especially compared to the 2nd `df`. In the scenario you are mentioning, I reckon that it's dangerous to do so because your broadcasted `df` would be tranferred to each and every worker node completely.

Comment: @BlueSheepToken I mean do the two columns at the same time. Simultaneously not concurrently. Sorry.

Comment: @cph_sto Is there another way you would recommend to do the same job in pyspark? Am still a beginner in spark.

Comment: I would highly recommand to not broadcast (usually, if it is more than 10 MB you should not broadcast). Maybe in your case this works, but broadcast it only once. Afterwards, I do not think both columns could be created in a single task. And the last, but not the least, try to study the SPARK UI to find if the data are well balanced between workers.

Comment: How do I edit the code to reflect your idea?